# Получение купонов примененных к корзине

Tags: битрикс

Имеется шаблон Некстайп магнит на сайте. Но страница заказа полностью переделана. На странице корзины есть возможность ввода купонов, насколько я понимаю они каким то образом крепятся к корзине/памяти/еще где-то. Каким образом введенные купоны можно получить на странице заказа.
Пробую таким образом.

```
$basket = \Bitrix\Sale\Basket::loadItemsForFUser(
    \Bitrix\Sale\Fuser::getId(),
    \Bitrix\Main\Context::getCurrent()->getSite()
);
$order  = Bitrix\Sale\Order::create( "s1" , \Bitrix\Sale\Fuser::getId());
$order->setPersonTypeId( 1 );
$order->setBasket( $basket );
$discounts  =  $order->getDiscount();
$discountsRes  =  $discounts->getApplyResult();
```

В `$discountsRes` содержится массив всех скидок, но массив с купонами пуст. При этом если вернемся на этап корзины, купоны отображаются на странице. Каким образом можно получить этот массив? Где хранит его битрикс?

Дополнение
Если на странице заказа выполнить

```
\Bitrix\Sale\DiscountCouponsManager::init(
    \Bitrix\Sale\DiscountCouponsManager::MODE_MANAGER, 
    array('userId' => $USER->GetID())
);
\Bitrix\Sale\DiscountCouponsManager::add('123456789');
\Bitrix\Sale\DiscountCouponsManager::saveApplied();
```

То он появляется при пересчете корзины и выводится на странице корзины. Но при обновлении страница заказа он не выводится и не учитывается.

Answer (score 1):

Информация о введеном купоне видна на странице корзины, так как это форма. Сам же купон применяется не к корзине, а к заказу. Поэтому информацию о примененном купоне можно получить зная ID заказа.

Для версий битрикса старше 16 и модуля `sale` выше 15.0.x, следующий способ позволяет зная ID заказа получить примененнный к нему купон:

```
$couponList = \Bitrix\Sale\Internals\OrderCouponsTable::getList(array(
    'select' => array('COUPON'),
    'filter' => array('=ORDER_ID' => ID_заказа)
));
while ($coupon = $couponList->fetch())
{
   echo $coupon['COUPON'];
}
```

Для вашего случая можно организовать передачу данных между компонентами корзины и оформления заказа: через сессию, через куки, через параметры компонентов.

Как вспомогательный вариант можно попробовать в нужном шаблоне компонента сделать распечатку массива `$arResult` в котором лежат полученные данные:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($arResult);
echo '</pre>;
```

Вполне вероятно что данные о купоне в нем передаются, просто нет вывода, так как в момент оформления заказа должна произойти привязка введенного в корзине купона к созданному заказу.

Comment: Так я нахожусь еще до созданного заказа. По сути в корзине, откуда корзина тянет купон. Кеш посмотрел, хранилище, нигде нет на фронте.

Comment: В корзине у вас есть поле для ввода купона. Купон же применяется к заказу, а не к корзине. К тому же в вопросе вы спрашиваете `Каким образом введенные купоны можно получить на странице заказа`. Так как по вашим же словам `При этом если вернемся на этап корзины, купоны отображаются на странице.`. А сейчас когда я привел вам пример как на странице заказа можно просмотреть примененные к нему купоны вы пишите, что надо смотреть в корзине. Определитесь что, где и на какой странице вам нужно, где и что у вас есть, скорректируйте вопрос, при необходимости.

Comment: Я написал в вопросе. Есть страница с корзиной на ней применяется купон и он там отображается. Далее перехожу в заказ. Страница заказа - здесь купон не появляется, тот который на странице корзины ввели. Но если я на этой странице добавляю купон (код в вопросе), то при обновлении страницы его как будто и не вводил, тоесть список пуст. Но на странице корзины он отображается. Как мне получить массив, заказа еще нет, я его не сохраняют в базе, т.е. нет операции $order->save();

Comment: @Алексей я повторюсь: *Купон применяется к заказу*. В вашем случае необходимо реализовать передачу информации из компонента выводящего корзину в компонент оформления заказа. Каким образом - на ваше усмотрение: можно через сессию, можно через куки, можно через параметры компонентов. В корзине сохраняете введенные купоны, затем передаете их компоненту оформления заказа и выводите, т.к. сам купон применяется к заказу, а не к корзине.

Comment: Видимо я тупой и не могу правильно формировать мысли. Но вы натолкнули меня на другую мысль "что сделать в моем случае что бы заработало" (все уже реализовано в битриксе и не надо свои велосипеды изобретать). Благодарю!))

Comment: @Алексей можете поделиться? Ваш вопрос просто заинтересовал. Насчет формирования мыслей, может я где-то потерялся в вопросе и не до конца сразу уловил.

Comment: я некомпетентен в BX как Вы (ранее не сталкивался). Есть корзина - с ней все ок. Есть Заказ - полностью изменена, почти ничего нет от BX. На этапе заказа мне было не понятно откуда взять эти купоны, ведь заказа у нас еще нет как такового, а купоны уже как-то у корзины имеются (у заказа, хз как объяснить). `... на ваше усмотрение: можно ... через параметры компонентов.` - через параметры компонентов! Есть же массив $arResult (не разбираюсь как он получается), но в нем все есть что мне нужно (даже больше), т.е. у меня всегда он был, а я и не знал что в нем есть эта информация.

Comment: Массив $arResult как раз и содержит данные которыми обмениваются компоненты. Его распечатка очень часто спасает.